# Force entity framework to use multiline/multirecords sql syntax

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Is there a way that entity framework can when sending queries to server, use next syntax:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (id, name) VALUES (1, 'Bob'), (2, 'Peter'), (3, 'Joe');
```

As this would boost performance. I'm using sql profiler and see that by default it uses singular insert e.g.

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (id, name) VALUES (1, 'Bob')
INSERT INTO MyTable (id, name) VALUES (2, 'Peter')
INSERT INTO MyTable (id, name) VALUES (3, 'Joe')
```

I know this feature is not supported by numerous reasons such as sql server maximum packet size,.... Just asking if it might be.

Comment: I think the first syntax is for convenient, it is always resolved to the second query. And that does not mean there are 3 round trips to db, they may all be sent together in a single round trip.

Comment: Actually I think that EF uses roundtrips also with AddRange

Comment: Looking with sql profiler, entity framework sends each query to the server. Of course in transaction e.g.: begin transaction insert into t1 () values(), insert into t1()values(), commit. Even with AddRange it does the same. Even if Entity framework does send all three queries in a single round trip, sql server executes them separatly.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues on Stack Overflow related to insert performances. Some related to the context that become huge so also an Add to the DbSet gets slower and some related to the DBMS performances.

If you use SQL Server you can try this helper
https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/
it uses System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy so it should be faster than Insert.

Comment: I created custom multirecords insert method, which inserts like mentioned in my post insert into table (c1, c2) values (a,a), (b,b), .... but hit the limit of sql server: maximum 2100 sql parameters are allowed. So yes, I believe if you want to insert larget amount of records fast, there is not other option but to use SqlBulkCopy.

Comment: You could avoid parameters (taking care about sql injection) if you are more confident with your procedure. If you want to be national settings independent (I'm in Italy so I have to handle it every day) just remember to use single quotes to specify the dates and use yyyymmdd format (supported if specified in single quotes). Just one question if you can answer, did you generate the queries starting from DbSet?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but used typical entity framework usage in my case: class TaxablePersonContext : DbContext, using (TaxablePersonContext context = new TaxablePersonContext()) TaxablePerson p = new TaxablePerson() ... set properties ... context.Add(p). Then Entity framework generated queries.